# How to solve non-identifiability problem in point estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, identifiability, point-estimation

I am working with a normal model $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2(\theta))$, where $\sigma^2(\theta) = \frac{1}{e}\cos^2(\theta)+e\sin^2(\theta)$. My goal is to estimate $\theta$ within the range $[0, 2\pi]$.

My desire is the point estimation of $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$. However, the maximum likelihood estimator is not consistent because this model produces a likelihood function with 4 maxima.

I am wondering if there is a reparametrization or another method that could help solve the non-identifiability of $\theta$, given that I don't have prior information about it.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or advice you may have.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $e$?  A parameter?  A known constant?

Comment: is exp(1) a known constant

Comment: If you plot your function $\sigma^2(\theta)$ vs. $\theta$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ you will see that the function is periodic with period $\pi$ and symmetric around $\pi/2$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$.  There is not going to be anything you can do about that while maintaining either your functional form or the desired range of $\theta$, so you'll have to change one or the other (or both.)  I'd probably just limit $\theta$ to $[0, \pi/2]$ and note that you can't distinguish between $\theta \in [0, \pi/2], \theta \in [\pi/2, \pi], \dots$.